# How to add prefix to gae datastore entity (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've seen some people define model in gae like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

def user(db.model):
  name = db.StringProperty(default='')
  ...
```

and when deployed to gae, the entity name becames `app1_user`, that's a good practise, but I haven't find the code where the preficx `'app1_'` was added.

how could I do so?
and, I'm using ndb

Comment: I have not seen that anywhere. Not sure how it would help, and will only make entities take up more storage.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Django does that, and the prefix is the app/folder where model.py is in see->[django-doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/). I am not sure if it's inherited to GAE when you create a django based app

Comment: @georstef is right, it's exactly what you said. I've seen it in a django based gae app. Now I'm developing a blog engine use flask on gae, and also want to have this feature but don't know how.